# What type of neural network do I need?

Tags: neural-networks

I am working on protein structure prediction.

Suppose, I am solving a problem using Neural Networks. I know how many inputs and outputs there will be in the model, as it directly depends on the problem statement.

However, how do I know:

- **[What type of neural network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpdyb.png) do I need to apply to optimally solve my specific problem?**

Comment: I think here are some decision flowcharts available that can help you navigate this set of possible solutions. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for, or do you have a specific problem that you want help analysing to decide a good fit?

Comment: You should bear in mind that many problems at the top level can be solved in multiple ways, and some of the ways of solving the same problem could point at different neural network architectures (for simplicity we can count "don't use a NN" as one of the architectures here too). So a good direct answer to your question may leave you with further questions, because you have not made some key analysis or decisions about your problem

Comment: @NeilSlater, I am actually working on protein structure prediction. However, I also want to know the general process of selecting a neural network.

Comment: I don't think any of the architectures in your diagram are that great for protein structure. You probably want to look into graph convolutional networks (GCNs). See e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aGgNas9IA4 (about protein function, so not identical architecture to what you want, but shows that your diagram is not complete in the area you want to work in)

Comment: Also of course this: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03348-4

Comment: please state the problem your trying to solve.   it depends on whether the problem is linear or nonliner, text or timeseries, or binary or multiple classification.   You can use cnn or lstm or dense layer networks to solve many of the problems.